# Recognizing small vessels on CT images with unet

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

We're trying to generate a 3D pulmonary vascular tree by using the CT images. We're using VGG-16 as the encoder and the identical layers(without transferring the weights) as the decoder. Since the CT images are dramatically different than the images used on the VGG-16 training, fine-tuning is applied to the entire network.

The dataset consists of over 22000 training data and 8000 validation data. For each epoch, the network randomly chose 2000 training data and 800 validation data. And also, the batch size is chosen as 3.

Our problem is network is not able to segment the small vessels. As an example, we have the:

Original CT image as:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVvMO.png)

Label of the image:
[labeled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3I1s.png)

Prediction of the network:
[predicted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsypQ.png)

So far, we tried to change the network structure from the standard u-net to the u-net with transfer learning. Also, we tried to make the images brighter but those changes did not solve the problem.

I can also provide the preprocessing code:

```
# Pixel intensities we interested in
pixel_range = (-6000, 6000)

# Normalizing the images
image = ((image-pixel_range[0]) / (pixel_range[1]-pixel_range[0]))*255
image[image>255] = 255
image[image<0] = 0

# Histogram equalization
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
histogram_equalized_image = clahe.apply(image)

# Enhancing the image
maxIntensity = 255.0
phi = 1
theta = 1
ratio = 1.5
enhanced_image = (maxIntensity/phi)*(histogram_equalized_image/(maxIntensity/theta))**ratio
enhanced_image = np.array(enhanced_image, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Segmenting small vessels is not a trivial task for convolutional neural networks. To be honest, you would probably have more luck segmenting lung area and then using simple algorithm like thresholding to get pulmonary vessels.

You provide too litle information, but if I were to comment on your code, I would stick to standard U-Net architecture first. Also, your pixel range "enhancing" is a little strange. Try clipping the some intensity values to limit the pixel range you're working with. Try working with image augmentations. I'm not sure why you're using only 2000 image slices per epoch. Make sure your data is split randomly per-patient, not per-image.